# AutoSize on Panel not working when creating a panel pro-grammatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have made a `panel` which I create pro-grammatically. When this panel is created I add it to the WinFrom. I then add a `textbox` and a `label` to the `panel`. This all works fine if I set the panel to the correct height and width however I don't want to do this as there may be more than one textbox added to the panel. The issue I'm having when I set the Autosize to True it doesn't Autosize the panel accordingly.

My code is as follows

```
    Private Sub CreateTextBoxFieldPanel(ByVal multiLine As Boolean, ByVal textBoxName As String, ByVal labelCaption As String, tag As String, textBoxText As String)
        'label plus textbox
        Dim _NewPanel As Panel = CreatePanel(textBoxName, textBoxText)
        Dim _NewLabel As Label = CreateLabelPanel(labelCaption)
        Dim _NewTextBox As TextBox = CreateTextBoxPanel(textBoxName, multiLine, textBoxText)


        _NewPanel.Controls.Add(_NewLabel)
        _NewPanel.Controls.Add(_NewTextBox)
        Me.Controls.Add(_NewPanel)
    End Sub
    Private Function CreatePanel(ByVal textBoxName As String, ByVal textBoxText As String, Optional ByVal textBoxWidth As Integer = DefaultTextBoxWidth) As Panel
        'returns panel with default properties
        Dim _NewPanel As New Panel
        _NewPanel.Name = textBoxName
        _NewPanel.Text = textBoxText
        _NewPanel.Top = topForNextControl
        _NewPanel.Left = 17
        _NewPanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(0, 0)
        _NewPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right
        _NewPanel.TabIndex = tabIndexForNextControl
        tabIndexForNextControl += 1
        _NewPanel.AutoSize = True
        _NewPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Return _NewPanel
    End Function

    Private Function CreateLabelPanel(ByVal LabelCaption As String) As Label
        'returns label with default properties
        Dim _NewLabel As New Label
        _NewLabel.Text = LabelCaption
        _NewLabel.Top = labelInPanel
        _NewLabel.Left = 0 
        _NewLabel.AutoSize = True
        _NewLabel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left
        _NewLabel.TabIndex = tabIndexForNextControl
        _NewLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        tabIndexForNextControl += 1
        Return _NewLabel
    End Function

    Private Function CreateTextBoxPanel(ByVal textBoxName As String, ByVal multiline As Boolean, ByVal textBoxText As String, Optional ByVal textBoxWidth As Integer = DefaultTextBoxWidth) As TextBox
        'returns textbox with default properties
        Dim _NewTextBox As New TextBox
        _NewTextBox.Name = textBoxName
        _NewTextBox.Multiline = multiline
        _NewTextBox.Text = textBoxText
        _NewTextBox.Top = labelInPanel + textBoxInPanel
        _NewTextBox.Left = 0
        _NewTextBox.Width = 200

        If multiline Then
            _NewTextBox.Height = 20
        End If

        _NewTextBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right
        _NewTextBox.TabIndex = tabIndexForNextControl
        tabIndexForNextControl += 1
        Return _NewTextBox

    End Function
```

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just needed to anchor everything to the top left

Comment: Rather than anchoring the controls, dock them to the top instead and set the desired margins.